# Does the size of the value affect the size of the index in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I have a set of IDs which are numbers anywhere between 8 and 11 digits long, and there are only 300K of them (so not exactly sequential etc.). These are stored in `collection A`.

I have a `collection B` with millions of entries in which every entry has an array of these IDs, and every array could have thousands of these IDs. I need to index this field too (i.e. hundreds of millions, potentially up to a billion+ entries). When I indexed it, the index turned out to be very large, way over the RAM size of the cluster.

Would it be worth trying to compress the value of each ID down from 8-11 numbers into some small alphanumeric encoded string? Or simply re-number them from e.g. `1 - 300,000` sequentially (and maintain a mapping of this)? Would that have a significant impact on the index size, or is it not worth the effort?

Answer (score 0):

The size of your indexed field affects the size of the index. You can run a `collStats` command to check the size of the index and compare the size of your indexed field with the total size that MongoDb needs to create the index.

Mongo already performs some compressions on indexes so trying to encode your field in an alphanumeric encoded string is probably not going to have a benefit or a marginal one.

Using a smaller numeric type is going to save a small amount of size in your index, but if you need to maintain a mapping, it´s probably not worth the effort and it is probably overcomplicating things.

The size of the index for a collection with 300K elements only indexing the 11 digits ID should be small, something around a few Mb. So it´s very likely that you don't have
storage or memory issues with that index size.

Regarding your second collection, if you reduce some bytes in each ID, you can get some reduction of the size of the index.

e.g. Reducing the size of each ID from 8bytes to 4bytes and having about 1Billion elements, you are reducing some GB the size of the index.

Reducing the size of the index and the collection B some GB could be an interesting save, so based on your needs, it could worth the effort to modify the IDs to use the smallest type possible. However, you could still have or you could have it in the near future if the collections keep growing, the memory issues due to the index not fitting in memory. So sharding the collection could be a good possibility.

Comment: Makes sense. However it's the second collection I'm worried about (I just edited the original question to further make that clear) since it has many entries with many large arrays of these numbers. So would using a smaller numeric type be worth the overhead hassle at the scale of e.g. 10M entries, each with an array of ~100 of these numbers each which need to be indexed to reference against the 300K collection?

Comment: I've updated the answer to take into account that second collection.

Answer (score 0):

Hashed Column index you can create which will give more or less same performance in case you interested more on saving the size of index.

You can check with some data how much % size of data you saving for index and performance impact and take decision